# Is there a way to check if the spoken command contains certain 'keywords' in windows speech recognition?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

For example, currently I have many different variations of how I could possible say one sentence/command. If I wanted tomorrow's date, I could say "What is tomorrow's date?" because I have that down as Grammar in my application. However, I could not say "What's tomorrow's date?" or "What will tomorrow's date be?" because I do not have them in my Grammar. Is there a way to check if the spoken command contains certain 'keywords' like "tomorrow" and "date". This would help because then you could say anything and as long as the recognition engine hears the keywords, it will execute the command.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SpeechRecognitionEngine recoEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
            Choices generalCommands = new Choices();
            generalCommands.Add(new string[] { "what is tomorrow's date", "whats tomorrows date", "what will tomorrows date be" });
            GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
            gBuilder.Append(generalCommands);
            Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);

            recoEngine.LoadGrammar(grammar);
            recoEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            recoEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            recoEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(SpeechRecognized);
        }

        private void SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            string speech = e.Result.Text;

            switch (speech)
            {
                case "what is tomorrow's date":
                case "whats tomorrows date":
                case "what will tomorrows date be":
                    MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see, I have 3 different variations of how I can ask for tomorrow's date. I want to it to check the speech for keywords and then execute the command. I have tried something like this

```
if (speech.Contains("tomorrow's") && speech.Contains("date")
{
    //...
}
```

To do this, I did change my Grammar around but it still didn't work. I hope I have made this clear enough and I will appreciate any answers or comments.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, instead of having a switch statement for what was said, you could have an if statement set up like:

```
if (speech.Contains("tomorrow") && speech.Contains("date"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString());
}
```

This will allow for much more flexibility such as, "What will the date be tomorrow?" or "Give me tomorrow's date."

I realize that this is really late and you have probably moved on, but I am putting this hear for people in the future who might be curious.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression. 
Instead of the switch, do:

```
Regex.Match(speech, @"\btomorrow(')*s\b\s+\bdate\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

That will match the three cases you have, and also the following, for example:

- "tomorrow date"
- "tomorrow's date"
- "tomorrows date"
- "tomorrows         date"

Will not match:

- "date tomorrow"
- "tomorrow dates"

Answer (score 0):

> However, I could not say "What's tomorrow's date?" or "What will tomorrow's date be?" because I do not have them in my Grammar.

To answer this your question, it's possible to insert placeholders into the grammar, see docs on [AppendWildcard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.grammarbuilder.appendwildcard(v=vs.110).aspx). However, for the best accuracy it's recommended to include all the possible choices in the grammar, this way you will be able to accurately handle user input and understand how to handle different user requests. You could usually spend ten minutes writing all possible variants and get a good coverage of possibilities.